Drupal updating to 10.2.6 fails "autoconfigure" on core
I came here because after a day of searching I didn't resolve my issue.
I tried to update a drupal system to 10.2.6 from 10.1.8 (since its not maintained on security release now).
Luckily I remembered we have a test env, so i proceeded on the test and followed the steps.
First updating Drush as required, then composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies
Since i use Core-recommended.
Here is composer.json:
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^2.0",
        "defuse/php-encryption": "^2.4",
        "drupal/animated_gif": "^2.0",
        "drupal/captcha": "^2.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^10.2",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^10.2",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^10.2",
        "drupal/dxpr_theme": "^5.2",
        "drupal/metatag": "^1.26",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.2",
        "drush/drush": "^12.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "phpstan/extension-installer": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "^10.1"
    }
}

Everything worked but when i came back to my site it has now an error:
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The configuration key "autoconfigure" cannot be used to define a default value in "core/core.services.yml". Allowed keys are "public", "tags", "autowire". in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\YamlFileLoader->parseDefaults() (line 161 of /var/www/suneris/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/YamlFileLoader.php).
I looked around and tried to change the "autoconfigure" key, but when i do that even drush stops working since the services aren't recognized anymore.
Im on a dead end and even trying to revert to 10.1.8 doesnt solve .
Edit: here is the error when i try autowire:true instead of autoconfigure on core.services.yml :
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException: Invalid service "plugin.manager.help_section": method "Drupal\help\HelpSectionManager::setSearchManager()" does not exist. in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\AbstractRecursivePass->getReflectionMethod() (line 218 of /var/www/suneris/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/AbstractRecursivePass.php).
